# Broken code upgrading to d3.js v4.0

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code in my js file:

```
d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
svgContainer = d3.select("#MainDiv")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({
        width: 1920,
        height: 932,
        version: 1.1,
        xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        viewBox: "-40, -40, 2810, 1940",
        "class": "borgModuleDesigner"
    })
    .on("contextmenu",
        function() {
            d3.event.preventDefault();
        });
```

This code worked fine when using d3.js v3.5.17. I just upgraded to v4.0.0 and I now get the following error:

```
Unable to get property 'on' of undefined or null reference
```

I can't find what has caused this to break. What do I need to change to get this to work in v4?

EDIT:

Thanks to Gerardo, I have now got my code to work. Use attr if only one attribute is defined, attrs if more than one. The following snippet of code now works with d3.js v4.0, as long as I add the reference to d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js:

```
var BorgAnalogue = function (container, object) {
var d = [{ x: object.X, y: object.Y, moveX: object.X, moveY: object.Y }];
var analogue = container.data(d).append("g").attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; }).call(onDragDrop(dragmove, dropHandler))
    .attr("id", "A" + object.ModuleNumber).attr("title", "Analogue " + object.ModuleNumber + " - brIQ Size: 14&#10;Label = " + object.label + "&#10;Source = " + s).attr("class", "masterTooltip")
    .on("mouseenter", mouseenter).on("mouseleave", mouseleave).on("mousemove", mousemove).on("mousedown", mousedown).on("mouseup", mouseup);
analogue.attr("desc", "Analogue-Analogue Module Parameters-738-470");
analogue.append("rect").attrs({ x: 20, y: 0, width: 220, height: 25, fill: "#FFFFFF", stroke: "black", "stroke-width": 1 });
analogue.append("text").attrs({ x: 43, y: 20, "font-family": "arial", "font-stretch": "condensed", "font-size": "20px", fill: "black" }).text(object.label);
analogue.append("rect").attrs({ x: 20, y: 25, width: 220, height: 55, fill: "#F5F5FF", stroke: "black", "stroke-width": 1, id: "highlight" });
analogue.append("path").attrs({ "d": "M 20,35 a10,15 0 0,0 0,30", fill: "#FFFFFF", stroke: "black", "stroke-width": 1, "class": "analogDrop", "id": "s-50" }).on("mouseover", overNode)
    .on("mouseout", outNode);
```

}

Note the mix of attr and attrs.

Comment: check the edit in my question: `selection-multi` is not part of the default bundle, you'll have to load it separately, as I did. Regarding your other problem, the best idea is opening a new question.

Comment: I don't understand why attr worked previously. I also don't know the difference between selection-multi and selection. What makes my object multi-value?

Comment: Because you used an object, with several key/value pairs. Compare `.attr({x:foo, y:bar})` with `.attr("x", "foo").attr("y", "bar")`.

Comment: Actually, even a single key/value pair like `attr({x: foo})` will not work in D3 4.x. You'll have to use `attrs` and link the `selection-multi` microlibrary.

Comment: There seem to be quite a few breaking changes. I wish they would make an upgrade guide like the jQuery team do.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, between that link and your help, I have now got my code working in v4. I have just added a snippet of working code to my question. I think I now see the difference between when to use attr and attrs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change is minimal, just one letter: `attrs` instead of `attr`. That's because you are using a multi-value syntax (your object). Check the API:

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi

So, the code should be:

```js
svgContainer = d3.select("#MainDiv")
    .append("svg")
    .attrs({
        "width": 1920,
        "height": 932,
        "version": 1.1,
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "viewBox": "-40, -40, 2810, 1940",
        "class": "borgModuleDesigner"
    })
    .on("contextmenu",
        function() {
            d3.event.preventDefault();
        });
```

```html
<div id="#MainDiv"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
```

Click "run code snippet", and you'll not see the error anymore.

But answering your question created another question: I could only make it work referencing the `selection-multi` as a separate link:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
```

Funny enough, it doesn't work using the "whole" D3 4.0 library. It *should* work using the complete D3 4.0 library:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

But, apparently, it doesn't.

EDIT: As it seemed, `d3.selection-multi` is not part of the default bundle. So, you'll have to do the way I did in the snippet. According to the API:

> For the sake of parsimony, the multi-value map methods have been extracted to d3-selection-multi and are no longer part of the default bundle.

Comment: That does seem to fix the code at that part. But now (in a later part of the code), I get `Unable to get property 'text' of undefined or null reference` I'll keep the answer unaccepted for a little while longer in case there's another solution. If there isn't I'll accept this and open a new query for the new error. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, you are very kind, but I'm not worried about accepting my answer: I'm worried about understanding what's happening in the code! After all, we all will have to move to v4 sooner or later...

Comment: It looks like in v4 that only core functionality is within d3.js library. Everything else is now in a separate library. This caused me some issues with chord diagrams yesterday when I updated. Read up on https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.0.0. The trick is to now determine what is "core" and what is now in a plugin.

Comment: I knew that we can link the small modules, but the default bundle doesn't combine *all* of them?

Comment: @wergeld, Yep, I just discovered that selection-multi is *not* part of the default bundle.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. I presume the new error I have will require a similar solution, I'll need to find the correct plugin. Something else must have changed in the new v4.0, because using attr in v3 worked fine.

Comment: Is there a place where I can see which components  are still part of the main bundle and which components are left out?

Comment: @Dblock247, none of them.