# Why does selection behave differently in d3 v4 vs v3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This works in d3 v3:

```
var svg = d3.select("#viz_pies").attr({
    "width": width,
    "height": height
});
// svg will be defined in v3, but not in v4
```

I've noticed this works instead:

```
var svg = d3.select("#viz_pies");

svg.attr({
    "width": width,
    "height": height
});
// svg will be defined in v4
```

I read https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection but I couldn't understand what was different for the above code.

EDIT: Also it seems I can't chain `style()` after an `attr()` either...

Comment: The problem here is the use of objects in `attr` or `style`. In D3 4.x, you have to use `selection-multi`. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38684633/5768908  And also this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38147209/5768908

Comment: That being said, just write `var svg = d3.select("#viz_pies").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);`, that is, each property in one individual `attr`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to rewrite my entire code since I heavily relied on `{}` syntax. Now I gotta figure out how to import `d3-selection-multi` using RequireJS... Are there any resources on how to require `d3` v4 libraries using RequireJS?

Comment: Mmm, I cannot help you here, because I never used RequireJS. But I'll tell you what: edit your question (to avoid it being closed as a duplicate) and ask for help regarding how require this mini D3 library using Require. Or, if you want, delete this question and write a brand new one about Require.