# creating svg element in codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I tried to create svg element using d3.js in code pen using following code spinet but it did not work for me, infect the height and width was were getting applied to the element as expected.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({
   width:800,
   height:800
});
```

Anyways the bellow code worked:

```
var svg = d3.select("main")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
```

Can anyone please help me why the first code spinet does not work in codepen, while it is working fine in local files?

Comment: What version of d3?

Comment: If you're using D3 v4.x, your question is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684597/d3-v4-cannot-read-property-text-of-null . And this one is even more similar to your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146012/broken-code-upgrading-to-d3-js-v4-0/38147209#38147209

Comment: your first code block worked fine for me when I set the width and height attributes like you did in your second code block. [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/haydenwagner/pen/EZNbMw)